# Inkscape does not open .svg file correctly

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word, svg, inkscape

I have an `svg` file that I have created using `draw.io` on Chrome.
When I open it in InkScape the blocks inside the .svg file that have teext in them are not shown correctly and it just shows [object].

I want to open the `.svg` in Inkscape and save it as an `.emf` so I can insert it into a Word document.

Why isn't the `.svg` file shown correctly in Inkscape? And, is there an easier way to insert the files created by `draw.io` in a Word document? I can export it to `.png` or `.jpg` but the quality is not good.

Comment: Has this been happened with more than one file or just that one?

Comment: Is it possible the svg is using a font that inkscape doesn't have available?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because draw.io SVG has text set with foreignObject which [Inkscape doesn't support](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=13086).